# Why is font-family bold if I added and using regular?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, next.js

I see this in browser when inspecting text: `font-family: TTHoves-Bold;`

I added these in globals.css in Next.js project:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "TTHoves-Bold";
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(../public/fonts/TTHoves-Bold.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TTHoves-Regular";
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(../public/fonts/TTHoves-Regular.ttf);
}
```

and using the right css rule:

```
.p_1 {
  font-family: "TTHoves-Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

<p className={styles.p_1}>Bármelyiket választod, nem fogsz csalódni.</p>
```

and even the text visually looks regular and not bold. But still why browser list a different setting?

Comment: Did you make the change recently and need to clear your cache? Have you restarted react/next? What is the actual rendered HTML and CSS??

Comment: You are right, I just restarted next.js in terminal at it solved, now it is regular, though it was a good joke from Szilard ;)